# php how to convert to different time zone?

Tags: php, time, timezone

i have there time stamps: `1319673600` and `1319785200`.

how do i convert them to GMT-7

for `1319673600` the time is:

```
GMT: Thu, 27 Oct 2011 00:00:00 GMT
GMT-7: Wed Oct 26 2011 17:00:00 GMT-7
```

for `1319785200` the time is:

```
GMT: Fri, 28 Oct 2011 07:00:00 GMT
GMT-7: Fri Oct 28 2011 00:00:00 GMT-7
```

I've tried : `gmdate("l, F jS, Y  g:i a", "1319673600")` but this give's em `Wednesday, October 26th, 2011 5:00 pm`

so what i want is for it to be `GMT-7: Wed Oct 26 2011 17:00:00 GMT-7` format

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateTimeZone`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

```
$dt = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone("US/Arizona"));
$dt->setTimestamp(1319673600);
echo $dt->format("r");
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
$timestamp = '1319673600';
$GMT_m_7 = date('D M d Y H:i:s', strtotime('- 7 hour', $timestamp));
echo $GMT_m_7;
```

Comment: Changing the timestamp does *not* change the timezone